# Do these results mean that I have found this exoplanet?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, amateur-observing, exoplanet, tess

Yesterday I was going through the TESS mission data on mast portal and after applying some filters I found some data. I started analyzing that data using the [lightkurve](https://docs.lightkurve.org/) library.

plot without using the periodogram script:
[image]

Running all the scripts I found this plot:

[image]

Then I searched after this star system on the *[exomast](https://exo.mast.stsci.edu/)* archive portal just to check that this system wasn't analyzed earlier by researchers and I am not wasting my time.
The portal didn't show any results which means that TESS researchers haven't studied this one yet and was not confirmed as an exoplanet.

Does this mean that I found it?

And what should I do now with this?

If this was already known I have no problem, this was fun to analyze.

Comment: After your updated question, this looks like a Hot (~4 days period) Jupiter (~1% transit depth around an F8 main sequence), but confirmation of a planetary mass companion would need a lot more work, as ProfRob has elucidated.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Ohh ok 
So what should i do next ?

Comment: As said in the answer below - you need to exclude false positives (such as eclipsing binaries, background objects) and find radial velocity data that fits the same period and has a mass commensurable with the rough expected mass of a planetary object. Those things are much harder to do though, and specialist pipelines are used for those. I am no expert in those things though.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape then how should I do this ?
pls can u share some resources at least

Comment: Frankly, if you don't know... maybe your best bet is to find an astrophysicist who's interested in helping do the next steps?

Comment: If you want to look into it further, you might want to reach out to the AAVSO, they are a "citizen science" organization connecting armature astronomer findings with professionals. https://www.aavso.org/exoplanet-section

Comment: Thanks 
I really appreciate this

Answer (score 23):

It could be an exoplanet transit (but that doesn't mean it is).

The star in question, TIC92352620, is an F8 main sequence star, which would be much larger than any plausible planet. If a planet transits in front of such a star, you expect a very rapid entry and exit to the eclipse with a flattish bottom, where any curvature can be attributed to limb darkening on the host star. The transit should repeat and look the same each time.

I'd say your potential transit passes that test, so it could be a Jupiter-sized planet on a 4-day orbit.

Even then, there are false positives that can produce similar results (e.g. the presence of a contribution of light from an eclipsing binary star that encroaches within the point spread function of the instrument - i.e. an unrelated star contaminating the data).

As to where you go from here, well, the discovery of an unremarkable transiting exoplanet is of interest, but not really headline news any more. A significant amount of work would remain to confirm the candidate and rule out possible false positives. At the least, because this is a bright star, one should obtain spectroscopy that shows any radial velocity deviations are very small, commensurate with a planetary nature for the companion.

Some information on eliminating (some) false positives in TESS data https://www.zooniverse.org/projects/nora-dot-eisner/planet-hunters-tess/talk/4733/2174551

Comment: I am very skeptical about this being a exoplanet, an asteroid might be the cause

Comment: umm
just to tell 
i have folded this plot using the periodogram to get this single dip

Comment: @ParamKasana I see. Why is the x-axis labelled as phase, but has units of days?? Anyway, how many transits do you have and do they individually look the same?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change the x-axis label in the resultant plot.
Yes individual transit dips look same
i will add the plot which is not folded in the post

Comment: @ProfRob can u provide some helpful resources to do further analysis (removing false positives, spectroscopy, and radial velocity) 
i really wanna continue this 
:)

Comment: One thing you can do is confirm there is no shift in the position of the source during the transit. @ParamKasana

Comment: @ProfRob can u tell how to ? just a little

Comment: @ParamKasana actually sorry for being skeptical about this claim, there wasn't much information so I couldn't know.

Comment: @FuriousNukefrostArcturus np

Answer (score 8):

Really hard to answer, a light-dip doesn't necessarily mean that you actually discovered a exoplanet. There can be multiple reasons to why this was not classified yet.

Asteroid belts can be a reason, multiple  large asteroids can cause significant dimming, by obscuring the star's light.

Exoplanets are found by running multiple analyzing processes, such as "wobbling" which means that even a small planet can cause a tiny, yet detectable tug on the star. A light-dip is hardly substantial evidence and can be easily taken for a asteroid belt.

As to what you should do with this discovery (in the unlikely case that you found a exoplanet(, I am afraid that is really hard to understand, as there are really few amateur astronomers who have made a significant discovery. Best bet would be to share the discovery on SIMBAD or some Astronomy catalog.

EDIT: After more information, this sounds more like a Hot Jupiter.

Comment: _Multiple large asteroids_? How on earth would that give you such a light curve?

Comment: @TonyK asteroids are theorized to produce more intense dimmings in Tabbys Star

Comment: Look at the light curves in [this Wikipedia article on Tabby's star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabby%27s_Star#Light_curve_gallery). None of them has the near-vertical sides and wide bottom of the OP's observations.